# Processing - No library found

Tags: processing, libraries

In Processing, I have the following error :

```
No library found for bezierVertex
Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the 'sketchbook'
```

I am trying to run "exemplePPhys2D_geeknessrain.pde", that can be found at

https://projets.pingbase.net/libro/projects/hub/repository/revisions/7/entry/EXEMPLES/pphys2d/examples/exemplePPhys2D_geeknessrain/exemplePPhys2D_geeknessrain.pde

The error is puzzling, since I did install the bezierVertex.jar library in

.\pphys2d\examples\exemplePPhys2D_geeknessrain\libraries, under 
.\pphys2d\examples\exemplePPhys2D_geeknessrain (which is what Processing shows as the sketch folder)

I searched the net (a lot), and I saw that some of the proposed solutions included other paths (see Wiki), like :

```
C:\Users\.........\Documents\Processing\libraries
C:\Users\.........\Documents\Processing\libraries\libraries
```

I now have the bezierVertex.jar library in all of the above.
However, Processing is still not finding it, and there's no way to just browse to the jar file from within Processing. The import library option does not seem to be able point to local folders (this would make things easier).

What am I missing ?

Thanks for your advice !

Comment: I'm sure you did `import bezierVertex.*;` in your code, right?

Answer (score 3):

You have to copy **bezierVertex.jar** in the libraries folder within your sketchbook.

On Windows:
`C:\Documents\Processing\libraries\bezierVertex\library\bezierVertex.jar`

On Mac OS X / Linux:
`~/Documents/Processing/libraries/bezierVertex/library/bezierVertex.jar`

If you just want to use the library for one project you can copy the jar-file into a **code**-folder within your sketch directory, i.e. `~/Documents/Processing/MySuperSketch/code/bezierVertex.jar`