# No library found for processing.video (JAVA)

Tags: java, processing

[Processing - No library found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903110/processing-no-library-found)

Hi.
I'm using Processing v3.3.3 and want to import processing.video package.

`import processing.video.*;`

This is the error I get:

```
No library found for processing.video
Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the 
'sketchbook' folder.
```

Where can I bezierVertex.jar library?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error says it all: you need to install the library before you can use it. If you're using the Processing editor, you do that from the `sketch > import library` menu. It's a two step process: first you have to install the library to your computer, and then you have to add the library to you sketch.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/libraries) is a tutorial that talks about using libraries in Processing.